# How to Highlight the Item (Listview) of Next Activity After Clicking the Item(Listview) of Previous Activity?

Tags: android, listview, android-activity, listviewitem

I have two `Fragments`. One `Fragment` Consist of Questions While Other`Fragment`  consist of Answers. For Example If one person click on Question(8) It means u can say that `Item` No 8, then it should go to next activity and highlight the Answer (8) of that Question. I am stuck. I shall be thank full to you.
Here is Some Code Which are sending Question No or list Item no to next Activity and next Activity code receiving this Question no and i saved it into `Interger` "a". Now what type of IF condition can work in the Next Activity?

> **First Activity**

```
lst.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            int index = position + 1;
            Intent it = new Intent(this.getActivity(), NextActivity.class);
            it.putExtra("Qlist", index);
            startActivity(it);


        }
```

> **Next Activity**

```
Intent it = getActivity().getIntent();

    int a = it.getIntExtra("Qlist", 0);

    String result=String.valueOf(a);

    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), ""+a, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

> ListView Adapter code of First Activity (using SQlite)

```
DatabaseAccess db=DatabaseAccess.getInstance(getActivity().getApplicationContext());



    List<String> lst;
    db.open();
    lst=db.getexamq();
    db.close();

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(ExamQ.this.getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, lst);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

> ListView Adapter code of Next Activity (using SQlite)

```
DatabaseAccess db=DatabaseAccess.getInstance(getActivity().getApplicationContext());



    List<String> lst;
    db.open();
    lst=db.getexamq();
    db.close();

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(ExamA.this.getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, lst);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: What have you got already? I'd love to help but a little bit of work from your side is appreciated.

Comment: I am trying But The Point is that I actually Want to know that where to start. .. but let me think.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use the intent Bundle to move the questionId or question No to the next activity
2. In the adapter of the Questions ListView, set a different background color for the question with a similar questionId. You can even set the background to have a fade animation or change to normal after a certain number of milliseconds or seconds.

**ALL THE CODE REQUIRED IS A LOT** Write something(some code), and we can help on the ListViewAdapter in case it doesn't work

**EDIT: SAMPLE FAST CUSTOM ADAPTER CODE**

```
    lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(ExamQ.this.getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, lst){
        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View v = convertView;
            final String examQ = lst[position];

            if (v == null) {
                LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                v = vi.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, null);
            }

            TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
            tv.setText(examQ);


            if( examQ.equals(result)) { // Unique identifier here
                v.setBackground(Color.RED); //Some other fancy color here
            }
            return v;
        }
    });
```

**However**, I just discovered you do not have a unique identifier for each question. So for the time being just use the question string and pass it to the next activity

Comment: I can move Question No to Next Activity. But can you tell me that If we use If Condition to match the Question no With Item No of Next activity and if they match then highlight it.is this posiible?

Comment: Yes, provide the adapter code, xml and activity code & I can help

Comment: Take a Look. As i Updated My Question with Code i have.

Comment: Provide the ListView Adapter Code

Comment: Take a look again.

Comment: Using My method, you would have to write a custom adapter. DO THIS, let me quickly add some code you will place there

Comment: ahan. I am waiting.

Comment: What Convert view for?

Comment: You mean that in if (exam question) condition, i should write a code which should pass it to the next activity?

Comment: Nope, this code goes in the second activity. In the first activity, pass the question in IntentBundle

Comment: Ok.. I will try .. Then i will let you know.. Thanks for all this help..

Answer (score 0):

Suppose You have a textview for each answer in the listview of second fragment. Then you can compare the question id in the `getView()` of adapter of listview in second fragment. Now when you find your answer just call `textview.setBackgroundColor()`.

Edit:
After `lv.setAdapter (adapter);` add

```
View v = lv.getViewAt(a);
if(v!=null)
    v.setBackgroundColor (Color.RED);
```

Comment: Can you explain me in some Code?? i mean do you have any code which can just tell me that how to check this Question No with Next activity??